# cant figure why the last image is coming out of the banner, could you please have a look?

Tags: css

The last image is pushing out of the banner can you help have a look at the css code the image is smage so it probably wont be the size.

```
<div id="bannercontainer">
<ul id="banner-ids">
<li class="banner-id">
<iframe src="http://rcm-uk.amazon.co.uk/e/cm?t=r0ab-21&o=2&p=48&l=ur1&category=consumerelectronics&f=ifr" scrolling="no" border="0" marginwidth="0" style="border:none;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</li>
<li class="banner-id">
<iframe src="http://rcm-uk.amazon.co.uk/e/cm?t=r0ab-21&o=2&p=20&l=ur1&category=kindle&banner=06V9WMDCWSM9ADC9C1R2&f=ifr" width="120" height="90" scrolling="no" border="0" marginwidth="0" style="border:none;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</li>
<li class="banner-id">
<script type="text/javascript">
var uri = 'http://impgb.tradedoubler.com/imp?type(img)g(16853792)a(1921176)' + new String (Math.random()).substring (2, 11);
document.write('<a href="http://clkuk.tradedoubler.com/click?p=3430&a=1921176&g=16853792" target="_BLANK"><img src="'+uri+'" border=0></a>');
</script>
</li>
<li class="banner-id">
<script type="text/javascript">
var uri = 'http://impgb.tradedoubler.com/imp?type(img)g(17412240)a(1921176)' + new String (Math.random()).substring (2, 11);
document.write('<a href="http://clkuk.tradedoubler.com/click?p=68951&a=1921176&g=17412240" target="_BLANK"><img src="'+uri+'" border=0></a>');
</script>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

the related css

```
    #banner-ids{
      display: block;
       width: 800px;
       height: 300px;
       padding: 0;
       background: #eee;
       border: 1px solid #000;
}

.banner-id{
   border: medium none;
   display:block;
   float: left;
    padding: 0 70px 5px 0;
}
```

Comment: If you would have provided a working example to use the Chromium Inspector on, I would have had a look…

Comment: can you update your post with http://jsfiddle.net/ link

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing the widths of the imgs or a working example

Comment: @feeela ok, check reacheasy.co.uk, the bodyshop logo is suppose to be in the banner but it is coming out and pushing other banner off their normal positio

Comment: There's a Body Shop logo on that page?

Comment: @JoshuaM  yes it is to be in the banner and not down there

Comment: @JoshuaM before the banner for women with image of a bag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the layout I am assuming that you wanted them to stack in a grid configuration, two on the first row and the latter two one the second row of your banner.  You can see that from the order of you `<li>` that the combined height of the 1st and 3rd exceeds your set height of 300 by 50px.  Just an observation that your grid will not stack properly inside the box.

The real problem is that your 3rd `<li>` is not stacking as intended by 'creating a new row.'  To create this effect you need to **add** *clear:left* to it to force this characteristic.

This is now force the second row but will cause it the row to not 'fit inside' *#banner-ids* To fix this 'broken' parent container **add** *`<div style='clear:both'></div>`* after the *`</ul>`* and before the *`</div>`* and **move** the styles from the *#banner-ids* to *#bannercontainer*  and **remove/adjust** the height

suggested code:

```
<div id="bannercontainer">
            <ul id="banner-ids">
                <li class="banner-id">
                    <iframe src="http://rcm-uk.amazon.co.uk/e/cm?t=r0ab-21&o=2&p=48&l=ur1&category=consumerelectronics&f=ifr" scrolling="no" border="0" marginwidth="0" style="border:none;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                </li>
                <li class="banner-id">
                    <iframe src="http://rcm-uk.amazon.co.uk/e/cm?t=r0ab-21&o=2&p=20&l=ur1&category=kindle&banner=06V9WMDCWSM9ADC9C1R2&f=ifr" width="120" height="90" scrolling="no" border="0" marginwidth="0" style="border:none;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                </li>
                <li class="banner-id" style="clear:left">
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        var uri = 'http://impgb.tradedoubler.com/imp?type(img)g(16853792)a(1921176)' + new String(Math.random()).substring(2, 11);
                        document.write('<a href="http://clkuk.tradedoubler.com/click?p=3430&a=1921176&g=16853792" target="_BLANK"><img src="' + uri + '" border=0></a>');

                    </script>
                </li>
                <li class="banner-id">
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        var uri = 'http://impgb.tradedoubler.com/imp?type(img)g(17412240)a(1921176)' + new String(Math.random()).substring(2, 11);
                        document.write('<a href="http://clkuk.tradedoubler.com/click?p=68951&a=1921176&g=17412240" target="_BLANK"><img src="' + uri + '" border=0></a>');

                    </script>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div style="clear: both"></div>
        </div>
```

and style

```
            #bannercontainer {
                display: block;
                width: 800px;
                padding: 0;
                background: #eee;
                border: 1px solid #000;
            }
            .banner-id {
                border: medium none;
                display: block;
                float: left;
                padding: 0 70px 5px 0;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the image is pushed out (height wise). 
then dont specify height:300px;
Then Cut that line.
(im not good in english so bear my errors).

```
#banner-ids{
      display: block;
       width: 800px;
       padding: 0;
       background: #eee;
       border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will put them all in line:

```
#banner-ids {
   display: block;
   width: 800px;
   height: auto;
   overflow: auto;
   padding: 0;
   background: #eee;
   border: 1px solid #000;
}

.banner-id {
   display:inline;
   float: left;
   padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
}
```

This will produce this result:
[image]